# editText in android

Tags: android

I am making an application and I have added an EditText in my layout.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when EditText is selected should open a dialog box, with some general text and an `OK` button. Which method can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide your code. it will help to find out the mistake.

Comment: @Reno Please dont demoralize someone

Comment: @Reno: You should mention *that* to the user, instead of posting demoralizing comments about his/her grammar. Suggest an edit to the post to fix grammatical and other mistakes. However, you should also consider that the community consensus is that there's nothing wrong with turning to Stack Overflow *before* using Google. If the question is a duplicate, find it and leave a comment. The users with enough rep will vote to close. You can also flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @Cody Gray just so you know i have done all three, (It was posted as a dupe in the dupe chatroom) I have edited his posts before. Begging for a solution is not the same as grammar mistake. I was not making fun of his grammar. Cut this thread please. I wont be replying here anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must try some thing like this

```
searchtext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                     showDialog();
            }
        }
     };
```

and here goes showDialog() code

```
private void showDialog()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder Main_Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    input.setText(ipAddress);

    Main_Dialog.setView(input);
    Main_Dialog.setTitle("Enter IP Address:");
    Main_Dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
                        //Do whatever
        }
    });
    Main_Dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your dilemma correctly, you'd set an OnFocusChangeListener for the EditText. Something like the following snip.

```
    EditText e = new EditText(this);
    e.setOnFocusChangeListener
    (
        new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (v.hasFocus()) {
                    showDialog(COOL_DIALOG);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Note, this seems like a somewhat odd user interaction. Why not just have them use the EditText for what it was made for? If you really want to do this, I'd suggest using a regular TextView or Button and use a click handler to pop the dialog. This would create a more "expected" interaction for the user.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to display the dialog when your EditView gets focus? I think overriding View.onFocusChanged() would be the way to go. If you want to track the detailed input into EditText, implement TextWatcher and use TextView.addTextChangedListener() to add it to the EditText instance.